# On the California bill of sale, who gets to keep the part of the paper where it says "save for your records"?

Tags: selling

I'm selling my car in California and I'm looking at the bill of sale: https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/file/bill-of-sale-reg-135-pdf/

It says on the DMV website that the seller should keep a copy of the bill of sale. Now I'm confused whether the two portions of the bill of sale on the page I've linked to go to the buyer and seller, respectively. Or whether the buyer gets to keep the whole page with two completed bills of sale and I just take a picture of that?

Not sure how to better describe what I mean. Again, if you follow the link above, the bill of sale has two parts. Do we fill out both parts during the transaction and then one goes with the seller and one with the buyer, or do both go to the buyer (presumably so that one can be surrendered to the DMV at the time of registration) and I, the seller, take a picture of the whole bill of sale?

Answer (score 1):

You should fill out both top and bottom with the same information and both buyer and seller should sign twice.  Then cut and save the BOTTOM for your records.

That's it...